# Javascript Object.prototype and circular references

Tags: javascript, prototype

I understand that in Javascript, variables are always assigned by reference which means that if I write :

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
b.foo = 'string';
console.log(a.foo); // prints 'string'
```

Right, so writing the following code returns an error:

```
var a = function(){};
var b = function(){};

b.foo=a;
a.bar = b;

console.log(a); // prints { [Function] bar: { [Function] foo: [Circular] } }
```

This is ok, for a.bar points to b and b.foo points to a, whose .bar parameter points again to b and so on. This is a circular reference.

Now, I noticed the following thing :

```
var a = function(){};
var b = function(){};

b.foo=a;
a.prototype = b;

console.log(a); // prints [Function]
```

I just replaced a.bar with a.prototype and now, I've got no circular reference error.

I presume this means that Object.prototype cannot be assigned a value by reference. Can anyone confirm? Is this an exception to the rule (at least if it is true there is one)?

Thank you !

Comment: nothing in javascript is ever assigned or passed by reference

Comment: @Esailija everything is passed as a reference. So if you do `var a = {}; var b = a;` you only get 1 object that is referenced both by `a` and `b`.

Comment: That's not an "error", that's a detection of the circular reference and refusal to recurse in when displaying a human-readable representation of it. A real error is `var a = {}; a.__proto__=a; //Error: Cyclic __proto__ value`

Comment: `var a = {};
var b = a;
b.prototype.foo='string';
console.log(a.prototype.foo); //prints undefined`

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa that's not what assign / pass by reference means

Comment: @Phrogz Ok, it's no error but note that no circular reference is spotted in the last example

Comment: @Esailija please explain what that is then

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa if you make `a`, refer to `b`, then changing `a`, will change `b`. As in, if I make `a = 3` then `b` will be `3` as well.

Comment: @Esailija That's exactly how it works with objects. For primitive types, as long as you don't change the original value, both of the variables actually point to the same value, until you change either one of the variables, which effectively creates a new value and changes one of the variables to point to the new value. That's reference assignment. It's not exactly the same as pointers in C etc, but that's still assigning a reference. Much like Java does with Strings.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa by changing, I mean assigning to something else. In javascript, if you assign `a` to something else, `b` won't be assigned to that as well (Doesn't matter if it's string, object or number). Do you see the light yet?

Comment: @Esailija That doesn't mean that JS does not assign references. Go read http://es5.github.com/#x8.7 if you don't believe me. Basically, if you modify a value, that is referenced by multiple variables, you don't actually modify that actual value, but first create a copy of that and then change the copy that was created. As I said before, if it doesn't work exactly like pointers doesn't mean that it's not referencing. In your example a and b are references to the same 3. If you did b++, you would get the a that references to the original 3 and b that references a newly created 4.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa it has nothing to do with what the internals do, javascript as a language doesn't support assign/pass by reference, you can't for example make a function that swaps the values of 2 variables

Comment: @Esailija the question was whether things are assigned by reference or value, and they ARE passed by reference. You're just pointing out that JS doesn't have C-style pointers, that's a totally different subject apart from having references.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa strictly, a variable pointing at a (non primitive) JS Object contains a reference to that object.  However when that variable is passed to a function a _copy_ of that reference is sent.  Hence JS is formally "pass by value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that seems to be only a anomaly of your console. In which browser do you encounter this? Opera's Dragonfly for example won't list any properties on functions.

Also, I haven't seen a console that whinges about circular references in a logged object...

Yet, the circular reference is there also in your second example. Just try to print `b.foo.prototype.foo.prototype.foo...` :-) It only won't be displayed as such, because the "`prototype`" property of functions is not enumerable (see [spec 13.2, #18](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2)).

Comment: I've tried this in Codeacademy's scratchpad [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/programming-intro/0#!/exercises/0/scratchpad)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would this one been explained? var a = {}; var b = a; b.prototype.foo='string'; console.log(a.prototype.foo); //prints undefined

Comment: Uh, ok. Try to run the same code in a built-in browsers developer console, that might help you understanding it.

Comment: @ the second question: your a/b object has no "prototype" property. You would need to set that first: var a={prototype:{foo:"string"}},b=a;

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error.  It's just a printing convention.